# NSMutableArray: Does initWithObjects start at index 0?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

when you declare an array and initialize it at the same time using `initWithObjects:` does the first object go in index 0?  and then sequentially fill the array?

example: Does the following declaration

`NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"zero", @"one", @"two", nil];`

result in:

```
test [0] = zero
test [1] = one
test [2] = two
```

?

Comment: NSMutableArray (like any sane array ;-) has 0-based indices. So, yes.

Comment: yes. You can reach them with the objectAtIndex method like this [test objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: Isn't this easy to check on your own by writing a small sample program?

Comment: okay thank you.  Why did I get voted down?  It is a good question for beginners like myself.

Comment: Starting array indexes at zero is a hangover from assembly days. If we were starting again, arrays indexes would start at 1, the same way we usually count things in the real world.

Comment: @ComDubh Counting from 1 is a hangover from ... sometime. If we were starting again, children would be taught to count from 0 in school :)

Comment: @Almo it would be if I had my mac with Xcode with me, which I dont

Comment: Then... why are you asking us? I can't see why you need to know this NOW if you're not at your computer.

Comment: I printed out my code to take with me to work.  Sorry for asking this sort of question, I won't do it again.

Comment: @ComDubh: There are some languages that use 1-based arrays: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array). Unfortunately the compromise option -- starting at 1/2 -- has never been given proper consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NSArray` and its subclass `NSMutableArray` manage ordered collections of objects.